# Autowire with Spring 4 and jersy

Tags: autowired

I am getting autowiring issue while using jersy with spring 4 .

Here is my dependency

```
     <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>infinispan-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jax.ws.rs}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am getting issue with CacheManager as below , CacheManager is not getting autowired.

```
    @Component
    @Path("/cacheservice")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public class DssCacheServiceImpl implements DssCacheService {

@@Autowired
private CacheManager cacheManager;

     }
```

and below is the cache manager definition

```
@Component
public class CacheManager {

    public EmbeddedCacheManager manager = null;

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadCache() throws IOException {
        manager = new DefaultCacheManager("META-INF/cache/infinispan.xml");
        System.out.println("manager " + manager.getCache("grossSalesCache"));
    }

    public EmbeddedCacheManager getManager() {
        return manager;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use @Autowired, you need to specify paths where you use @Component in the configuration file.

To XML-based configuration:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="..." />
```

To Java-based configuration:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages="...")
```